# Rails way of breaking down a large form into multiple steps?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the best way to structure a multi-page form to create and edit models in a database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3619551/what-is-the-best-way-to-structure-a-multi-page-form-to-create-and-edit-models-in)

Is there a "Rails" way of breaking down a large form for a model into multiple steps?

For example, in my HR software, `User` model has many attributes such as experiences, educations, addresses etc. It would be overwhelming for the user to see all these forms in one page. I would like to break them into pieces and present them step by step instead.

Is there a preferred way of doing this in Rails?

Comment: if you are fine doing that at frontend, you can do it easily by this plugin https://github.com/xoxco/jQuery-Multipage-Form

Comment: I am reluctant to use frontend solution because 

1. I want to use Rails validation

2. Go back and forth to edit data you submitted, and this is probably complicated with jquery alone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two way to do this

1) Using [Multistep Forms](http://railscasts.com/episodes/217-multistep-forms)

2) Using [Wizard](http://railscasts.com/episodes/346-wizard-forms-with-wicked)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [state_machine](https://github.com/pluginaweek/state_machine)  to create multiple step form. Here you can write validations for each state where each state can be assumed as each step in your case. Hope this helps you.